# dynamic datatype for field in mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.1

I have a model class as :-

```
class TestParam
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :parameter_id, type: String
  field :parameter_key, type: String
  field :range_max, type: String
  field :range_min, type: String
  field :unit, type: String
  field :multiple, type: Boolean
  field :value, type: Array or String

  embeds_in :test
```

end

Now my problem details is as:-

1) If field 'multiple' is true, then datatype for 'value' should  be array, else if field 'multiple' is false, then datatype for 'value' field should be string. How can we solve this problem using mongoid (5.1.0) ? Thanks, Happy Coding.

Comment: I think your simplest option is to remove the type and just use `field :value`...? For runtime type checking, you could possibly use a custom getter/setter.

Comment: thanks @JoachimIsaksson for quick response, I think your solution makes sense, I will try and update the solution.